# Email invite not working for non admin user - alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

If a non admin user create a site and invite people I am getting `0 invites sent 1 failure` error. These all are steps I tried,

I added the user to administrator group (strange the user cannot see the administrator tool, I tried both user from the active directory and from alfresco create user)

I tried adding the user to email contributor

**UPDATED**

After fixing the permission of data dictionary it is working but giving administrator privilege to the user is not working

Comment: Have you changed permissions on Data Dictionary space?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you I removed the Data Directory Space permission, only admin can see the data directory

Comment: That is the reason you are facing this issue. Because during sending mail alfresco use email templates which are stored inside that space and as you have removed permission it is causing issue. check by adding permission again.

Comment: But I added the user to administrator group still its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your remove Consumer access for GROUP_EVERYONE for the Data-Dictionary then you'll hit more issues then this one...

Instead of you should:

1. remove Consumer access for GROUP_EVERYONE for the Data-Dictionary
2. set inheritPermissions= false & GROUP_EVERYONE = Consumer for the child folders of Data-Dictionary. (here is a JavaScript nsippet for this task: http://ecm.vsemozny.cz/2013/03/tip-213-how-to-hide-data-dictionary-for.html)

Comment: But what about adding users to GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR. When I add a user to a administrator group still he is not getting the admin tools

Comment: why should you give a user admin permissions just to be able to invite a user to a site? Guess that is not the best solution for your requirement

Comment: Yes, but what if I need two people to manage the entire share application using their own login instead of using single admin login

Comment: then make them admins e.g. by adding them to GROUP_ADMINISTRATOR or by adding them to defaultAdministratorNames in your authenttication subsystem

Comment: correct group name is GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS

Comment: Yes that seem to be the problem thanks I changed the admin group name